# Difference between moduli spaces of supersymmetric vs non-supersymmetric theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, sigma-models, moduli

I have a basic conceptual question regarding the difference between moduli spaces in supersymmetric vs non-supersymmetric theories.

In usual non-supersymmetric theories, the existence of flat directions is usually associated with spontaneous breaking of some continuous global symmetry. The different vacua are related by symmetry and are physically identical with the motion along the moduli space corresponding to massless Goldstone modes. In particular we can describe these low excitations by a non-linear sigma model with target space the moduli space.

For SUSY theories this is not the case as this vacuum degeneracy is not protected by any symmetry. The different vacua are physically inequivalent. Now my question is, how do we know the low energy degrees of freedom are described by coordinates on the moduli space (or more precisely as a sigma model with target space the quantum moduli space) for SUSY theories. This seems conceptually very different from the non-SUSY case where the Goldstone modes take us between physically equivalent vacua?